# Is it possible to set the parent of a .NET WinForm to a native app?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

Is it possible to set the parent of a .NET WinForm to a native app?

So it acts like its child window?

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be an officially supported way to do this. It was discussed in the following article:

[Specifying Parent to a Windows Form Where Parent Form is in VB 6](http://www.devnewsgroups.net/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.windowsforms/topic44925.aspx)

Comment: The problem there seemed to be that VB6 didn't like have a C# form as it's child.